Phase shift full bridge converter - Ltspice simulation
I created a circuit for phase shift full bridge converter in Ltspice.
1st picture shows the circuit diagram
2nd picture shows the switch waveforms.
3rd picture shows the input and output signals.
Although the signals of the switches work properly, I cannot get proper results neither on the primary side nor on the secondary side of the transformer.
Is there a connection error in the diagram? Or is there an error in the spice driving commands? I would be very happy if you could help me.

Source: me

Source: me

Source: me
UPDATE

Source: me

No freewheeling diodes for the switches?

You have specced finite leakage inductance (L1), but nowhere for the energy to go, so very high flyback voltages are induced.

Something (in the definitions of pulses) seems to be "weird" ... Use some units.

A wild guess: add some resistance to your switches.

I added some resistance, It didn't work. You can see the updated picture (last schematic) do you have any other suggestion @Renan

I added freewheeling diodes, It didn't work again. You can see the updated picture (last schematic), do you have any other suggestion? @LarsHankeln

I added diodes for your suggestion, It didn't work again. You can see the updated picture (last schematic), do you have any other suggestion? @tobalt

@Verbal Kint   Sir,could you please help me out this topic, I will be very happy if you can.

(you can try to chat s.b. up.)

You could add the asc file (open in editor and paste the contents into your question in a code block)

I have no idea about how to do your suggestion. Is there any written guidance about it ?  thank you  @tobalt

Here is what I get simulated with microcap v12
Period used is 10 us. Number points used : 1000 per period.
Note that the steady state is "long" to appear.
Here is the starting ...  It does not show your "garbage".

Here is the "steady" state ...


Note the high current "shoot through". It last some "picoseconds".

Thank you for you simulation, you are right. It took time but here is the situation: although I made the simulation time a little bit longer. It didn't work again. You can see the last updated picture. Do you have any other solution ?  @Antonio51

The 1 kH is very "high", although it is a "perfect" transformer. But no "change" if you set it to 1 H only.

Some "units" in the V13 definition are "inconsistent" with others sources V14, V15 and V16 (0.000001 n versus 1 n).

Thank you for your comments.  As you know 1k Henry is there to to seperate the magnetising current and energy related current. Ideally it is infinite but Ltspice doen't work with infinite numbers so i put it so high (1k Henry) that the paralel equivalent will be close to 2.78mH.  @Antonio51

On the other hand, I changed the ''units'' and made them same, the result is still same @Antonio51

I am having very hard time struggling with Ltspice because No matter what I change in Ltspice, the result is still the same @Antonio51

Don't understand. The schematic I used is the same as yours, except the 1 kOhm resistor ... between the two outputs of the bridge.

What is the purpose of using 1kOhm resistore between the bridge ? I dont know the reason that is why I am asking. Maybe I should use as well @Antonio51

It was for testing the bridge without the inductive load. I did not suppress it. You can insert it as well, but It is not very useful. Just use step time of period /1000 (~10 ns).

The flyback diodes will protect the switches. This means that the voltage across the transformer winding will be also benign.
However, the voltage that you are probing (between the ideal transformer and its leakage inductance) is a fictional value because these two components do not exist in such separation in reality. As a consequence, the secondary obtains the same fictional voltage.
A better way to implement leakage inductance in LTspice than with a discrete inductor + ideal transformer is by using a non-unity coupling factor, e.g. k1 L3 L4 L6 0.99. Ideally, you also use the magnetizing inductance directly as the primary with adjusted values for secondary inductance.

Thank you for your suggestion. I followed your suggestion. I removed the L1 and used only the non-unity coupling factor and unfortunatelly didn't work again.  I am having very hard time struggling with Ltspice because No matter what I change in Ltspice, the result is still the same  @tobalt
